# Css not properly loading after opening home from link on page (Rails 5)

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a home page with a form which contains input fields and select fields to which I apply the following css:

```
.bootstrap-select>.selectpicker,
.bootstrap-select>.selectpicker:active,
.bootstrap-select>.selectpicker:focus,
.bootstrap-select>li:hover,
.bootstrap-select>li:active,
.bootstrap-select>li:focus{
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 100%;
    border: 0 !important;
    outline: 0 !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    background-color: white !important; 
}
```

This css is loaded properly when opening the home page ans styles are as expected, when I click the back button to go back to the home page, the css is still properly loaded and applied. But when I click on a link:

```
<%= link_to root_path do %>
    <%= image_tag "logo.png", class: 'navbar-brand'%>
<% end %>
```

The above css is not loaded (not visible within the Dev Tools). The select now gets default style, with border and also the dropdown arrow changed from one error pointing down, to two arrows (one down and one up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code to load css for `link_to` tag

```
<%= link_to root_path, method: 'get' do %>
    <%= image_tag "logo.png", class: 'navbar-brand'%>
<% end %>
```